# Kentico - How to publish pages when all tasks were deleted

Tags: kentico

I am publishing a couple of new pages using the Staging app. However, someone in my group might have deleted all the pending tasks. I tried looking at Staging > Pages, Data, Objects (instead of All Tasks) and published what's left in there but there're still things that are missing, the content tree in Production is not the same as Staging.

My question, is there a way to publish new pages from Stage to Production even though there're no pending tasks? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is.  If you go to Staging>Pages then select the page or node you want to sync.  You should first sync the page your selected on by clicking the green Synchronize current page button. Then click the gray Synchronize current subtree button to sync all the pages below the node you're selected on.

If there are tasks which error out in there, delete them and try the sync again.  Typical issue is it tries to sync the update before the create task and causes problems so thats why we remove them.

Comment: A better approach would be if you're totally clueless is to select root and synchronize entire tree. This will make sure nothing is missed and still retain the tree order on the target server. I agree with your second point. We should delete garbage tasks right after this.